# Postgres replication slot from kafka-connect is filling up

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

The replication slot created by a kafka-connector connector is filling up.

I have a postgres RDS database on AWS. I put the following parameter group option on it (only showing the diff from default)

rds.logical_replication: 1

I have kafka connect running with a debezium postgres connector. This is the config (with certain values redacted, of course)

```
"database.dbname"        = "mydb"
"database.hostname"      = "myhostname"
"database.password"      = "mypass"
"database.port"          = "myport"
"database.server.name"   = "postgres"
"database.user"          = "myuser"
"database.whitelist"     = "my_database"
"include.schema.changes" = "false"
"plugin.name"            = "wal2json_streaming"
"slot.name"              = "my_slotname"
"snapshot.mode"          = "never"
"table.whitelist"        = "public.mytable"
"tombstones.on.delete"   = "false"
"transforms"             = "key"
"transforms.key.field"   = "id"
"transforms.key.type"    = "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key"
```

If I get the status of this connector, it appears to be fine.

```
curl -s http://my.kafkaconnect.url:kc_port/connectors/my-connector/status | jq

{
  "name": "my-connector",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "some_ip"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "RUNNING",
      "worker_id": "some_ip"
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

However, the replication slot in postgres keeps getting larger and larger:

```
SELECT slot_name,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), restart_lsn)) as replicationSlotLag,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), confirmed_flush_lsn)) as confirmedLag,
  active
FROM pg_replication_slots;
           slot_name           | replicationslotlag | confirmedlag | active
-------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------
 my_slotname                   | 20 GB              | 20 GB        | t
```

Why does replication keep growing? As I understand, the kafka connect connector task that is running should be reading from this replication slot, publishing it to the topic `postgres. public.mytable`, and then the replication slot should decrease in size. Am I missing something in this chain of actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at [WAL Diskspace Consumption](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/postgresql.html#wal-disk-space).

The most common reason why the PostgreSQL WAL backlogs is because the connector is monitoring a database or a subset of tables from your database change much more infrequent compared to the other tables or databases in your environment and therefore the connector isn't acknowledging the LSNs frequent enough to avoid the WAL backlog.

For Debezium 1.0.x and before, enable `heartbeat.interval.ms`.
For Debezium 1.1.0 and after, also consider enabling `heartbeat.action.query` as well.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer because it usually is the answer. For Debezium 1.0, the heartbeat does not actually commit LSN, so the replication lag still grows. For 1.1, the query would be nice, but we use the ExtractField SMT, which is incompatible with any heartbeat at all (so it wouldn't work in 1.0 either). Tracked here https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-1909

Comment: Important piece of info from the linked docs: `"For users on AWS RDS with Postgres, a similar situation to the third cause may occur on an idle environment, since AWS RDS makes writes to its own system tables not visible to the useres on a frequent basis (5 minutes). Again regularly emitting events will solve the problem."`

Comment: What do you think about setting `max_slot_wal_keep_size` as a preventative measure? Though this could incur data loss for Debezium in extreme cases, it also ensures that Debezium cannot take down the whole db!

Answer (score 0):

Found this [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/debezium/c/39mmGEHii_8) where Gunnar mentions this -

The [core heartbeat feature](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-heartbeat-interval-ms) regularly emits messages to the heartbeat topic, allowing to acknowledge processed WAL offsets also in case only events in filtered tables occur (this is what you observe). [Heartbeat action queries](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-heartbeat-action-query) (which require the table and inclusion in publication) are useful to address situations with multiple databases, where the connector is receiving changes from one database with otherwise no/low traffic, again allowing to acknowledge offsets in this case.

- Gunnar

In the group discussion he mentions that we have to add this heartbeat table to the publication for this heartbeat query to work. This should help.

Comment: Edit: Update: 

Added the heartbeat table to publication. Didn't make any difference. This issue is still open.